# ServiceMix 4.2 - Using Endorsed Libraries

Tags: osgi, apache-servicemix

I was wondering whether SMX 4.2 has a concept of `endorsed libraries`?

My use-case is as follows:

There is a certain set of classes which need to be visible to all Java classes executing within the framework/SMX runtime. You might suggest to simply create a bundle out of the classes and export the relevant packages. However, in my SMX runtime, even WAR files can be deployed.
I don't think WAR's installed within the SMX framework can also utilise the Import/Export-Package feature. So I basically need to have this set of classes available to all other classes in a manner similar to say `java.util.List` is available.

In Tomcat, this can be done by placing the JAR within the lib/endorsed directory. However, I believe SMX doesn't declare any endorsed directories. So I created an endorsed directory within the `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\` folder. But my classes fail to get resolved.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can copy your jars into SMX_HOME/system and add declarations to SMX_HOME/etc/startup.properties with appropriate startup priority (I have used 30)